# Unique Array Values Using Foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => posts Object 
        ( 
            [title] => test1 
            [dbh] => DataBase Object 
                  ( 
                      [dbh] => PDO Object ( ) 
                  ) 
        )

    [1] => posts Object 
        ( 
            [title] => test1 
            [dbh] => DataBase Object 
                  (
                      [dbh] => PDO Object ( ) 
                  ) 
        )

    [2] => posts Object 
        ( 
            [title] => test2 
            [dbh] => DataBase Object 
                  (
                      [dbh] => PDO Object ( ) 
                  ) 
        )
)
```

I can't use array_unique(), because the the object can't to be converted to string

Comment: Yep it dosent work Catchable fatal error: Object of class posts could not be converted to string in ...

Comment: Is that coming from a database? In case it is, could you adjust the query to avoid duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to not use foreach. You should use for:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
    if ($array[$i] === $array[$j]) {
      unset($array[$j]);
      $array = array_values($array);
    }
  }
}
```

Foreach makes a copy of your array and loops over the copy, which makes it a bit more complicated to keep track of which duplicates is already tested/removed.

The code above will check if your `post` Objects are of the same instance, and remove if they are. You might want to check if they contain the same data, but are not of the same instance. Then you will have to expand the `if` line a little bit:

```
if ($array[$i]->title === $array[$j]->title && $array[$i]->dbh === $array[$j]->dbh) {
```

...for checking if title is the same and the `DataBase` objects are of the same instance.